# Getting Exception while using Java Mail for Office 365

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail

I am getting below exception while sending mails using Java Mail for Office365 Exchange server through our application in Windows Server. The Windows server is located in cloud platform. The same configuration(Exchange server details) with our application is working in windows 11 personal laptop and another Windows Servers ( is located in different cloud vendor) .

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.office365.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.office365.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.office365.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1959)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
    at com.grc.jframework.mail.FailsafeMailSender.sendInternal(FailsafeMailSender.java:146)
    at com.grc.jframework.mail.FailsafeMailSender.lambda$init$0(FailsafeMailSender.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 11 more
```

Is there anything to change/update configuration at Windows Server side?

**Below are the SMTP Server details:**

*smtp.sender.main.port* =  587

*smtp.sender.reserve.auth_type* = ANONYMOUS

*smtp.sender.main.auth_type* = TLS

*smtp.sender.main.host* = smtp.office365.com

*smtp.sender.reserve.port* = 25

*smtp.sender.main.timeout_sec* = 90

Comment: It says it cannot match the smtp.office365.com setting lookup with the server name it may be it should be office365.com   e.g. props.put("mail.smtp.host","darkstar.example.net");    // NOT smtp.darkstar.example.net

Comment: It sounds like the DNS your cloud platform uses doesn't resolve smtp.office365.com (possibly as a security measure?)

Comment: @SamuelMarchant smtp.office365.com is the right hostname.

Comment: so , metaphorically, if it were also a website , you would type into an address bar http://smtp.office365.com , NOT , ? http://office365.com ?

Comment: JUST A SERIOUS POINT HERE , "BOTH" office365.com  AND smpt.office365.com  are instantly redirected on the internet to Microsoft Corp. sites !!! meaning you cannot use those domains because they are owned by Microsoft (unless your Company is Microsoft) !!!! However, you can call that in an internal network that cannot be entered or exited to internet !!! ANOTHER SERIOUS NB NOTE , if they did not own those domains you would have serious restrictions on what you could say to or show to the public over internet because of the sub trademark branding belonging to a known registered product !!!

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Office 365 is used by thousands of companies. Presumably, the employer of Ram also uses Offce 365, and they want to send email through the SMTP server offered by Office 365, which is `smtp.office365.com`. The fact port 80/443 (HTTP(S)) of smtp.office365.com redirects, doesn't mean that other ports (like port 25/587 (SMTP)) aren't listening on that host.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant That is, if you telnet to smtp.office365.com port 587, you'll get response `220 AM0PR04CA0106.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 3 Dec 2023 11:20:51 +0000`, meaning there is an SMTP server listening on that host.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your inputs, tested with telnet to smtp.office365.com port 587. Getting response like `Connecting To smtp.office365.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect failed`. will raise the concern with admin team.

Comment: @Ram ..."offered by Office 365"... now i see , it IS microsoft Corp. operating that server, thanks. But in terms of it , did you do dynamic props() or did you configure web.xml with resource-ref element e.t.c. and/or context.xml with initial lookup new InitialContext() , (did you ever send unsolicited emails - any! may be the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Rotteveel suggested in comments, it was the issue with smtp.office365.com DNS and resolved with admin team.